# Should I use auto increment long variable or UUID for products/customers ID in a point of sale?

Tags: java, pos

I'm new in Java and I want to write a point of sale system by my own. I just want to know what should I use for identification number for my products, customers, categories, etc.

Can I use `long` for auto increment a new item as a good practice? Or should I use UUID or something similar?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: UUIDs by usual generation are more or less random, i.e. not guaranteed to be unique. If you can guarantee that you are generating in a single place/thread (i.e. never in concurrence) then you probably want increments. Can you?

Comment: I thought that UUIDs generation was unique always. Obviously, by your comment I was wrong. So, you recommend I use auto-increment variables like long?

Comment: @Yunnosch even if it's concurrent I would probably suggest increments. If performance was a problem you could reserve sequences of increments to reduce locking. I think of UUID's if it's not stored in a database, or if it's a large distributed system.

Comment: @Yunnosch The UUID class generates unique values.  See javadoc for the UUID class.

Comment: @vsfDawg Do you confirm that for generating in different places (including being on separate machines)? A class which guarantess uniqueness only for those values coming from the same instance does not contradict my comment. But your input is helpful if OP is in such a situation. That is why I asked. (I am thinking along https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier ; maybe we are not considering the same context.)

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes, the algorithm employed by UUID accounts for separate machines.  The link you provided describes the (un)likelihood of collision.  Note that I was merely challenging the notion that UUIDs were just random numbers.  Whether the OP should use UUID or an incrementing source is unclear as there aren't enough details.  If he's just prototyping then I'd go with UUID just out of simplicity.

Comment: Is this a question should to avoid that is explained in this help article? [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)